# Controlling FTP Accounts with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, ftp

Does anyone know how to control IIS (7.0+) from C#.NET?

I want to create and FTP site and then create an FTP users which has read and write access on different folders?

Is there some sort of library I can user for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [IIS ADSI Provider Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525121%28v=vs.90%29) to do this.

Here's a blog post with a sample for reading configuration: [HOWTO: Enumerate IIS website and ftpsite configuration (VBScript using ADSI)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151115070712/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/david.wang/archive/2006/06/08/howto-enumerate-iis-website-and-ftpsite-configuration-vbscript-using-adsi.aspx)
You should be able to adjust this sample to instead write the information you need and then just convert the script to C#.

This KB article should show you how to use ADSI from C#: [How to access ADSI objects in Visual C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20130717020352/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/315716)